# Qemu build properties set on real Samsung ROM?

Tags: android-emulator, qemu, android-emulator-plugin

I have access to a device I thought was a real Samsung J7 2016. However, I'm finding references to qemu, goldfish and ranchu in the root of the filesystem plus in the build properties I am finding  ro.adb.qemud=1 and ro.kernel.qemu.gles=1.

Why would all this be present in a ROM actually deployed on real hardware? Can I be sure this is running on real hardware and isn't emulated?

Of note, ro.kernel.qemu=0, but if that is true, why leave adb and opengl support for qemu active?

Sorry if I am being dense here, I genuinely don't understand why real hardware would have all this stuff for qemu...

Comment: Can you clarify whether the Samsung J7 2016 ROM had `ro.kernel.qemu` set to `1` or `0`?